# Поиск индексов наименьших значений в массиве

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Есть массив чисел типа int. Нужно вывести на экран 3 индекса наименьших чисел в массиве, при этом можно использовать только один цикл. Кто-то знает как решить такую задачу?

Comment: Создаете массив из трех элементов и по мере прохождения по основному массиву в этот созданный массив заносите индексы наименьших элементов.

Comment: Ну я так найду индекс одного наименьшего элемента, по моему что бы найти индексы других двух нужно будет еще один цикл делать, что по условию задачи запрещено.

Comment: Вы не указали язык реализации

Comment: @Bohdan Вам в любом случае нужно сравнивать новый кандидат на минимум с уже выбранными наименьшими элементами. Я думаю, что условие задание про единственный цикл имеет отношение лишь к основному массиву..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно хранить три минимальных значения в массиве и их индексы. (вернее, даже, достаточно только индексов)

```js
var Data = new Array(10);
// Fill array
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
  var val = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
  Data[i] = val;
  console.log(i + ' - ' + val);
}

// Prepare
var minData = [
  {idx: 0, val: Data[0]},
  {idx: 1, val: Data[1]},
  {idx: 2, val: Data[2]}
];

var findMax = function() {
  var res = 0;
  var max = minData[0].val;
  if (max < minData[1].val) {
    max = minData[1].val;
    res = 1;
  }
  if (max < minData[2].val) {
    max = minData[2].val;
    res = 2;
  }
  return res;
};

var maxIdx = findMax();

// Search
for (var i = minData.length; i < Data.length; i++) {
  if (Data[i] <= minData[maxIdx].val) {
    minData[maxIdx] = {idx: i, val: Data[i]};
    maxIdx = findMax();
  }
}

console.log('Indices:');
for (var i = 0; i < minData.length; i++)
  console.log(minData[i].idx);
```

Comment: input: [7,0,5,5,9,2,2,4,8,2], output [1,1,9] ?

Comment: @Igor Спасибо. Fixed.

Comment: Извините, сразу не разобрался, код желательно на java.

Comment: @Bohdan вам предоставили уже готовый читабельный код, переписать на Вам необходимый язык программирования не составляет труда.

Comment: @Bohdan Если мой ответ помог Вам, то ответьте его как правильный

Answer (score 0):

@Anton Shchyrov Спасибо за ответ, переписал код на java, может кому-то пригодится, лично мне такая задача попадалась несколько раз на тестировании при наборе на курсы по java в epam.

```
public class sort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    int[] minData = new int[]{0, 1, 2};
    int[] mass = new int[n];

    int a = 0, b = 10;
    //fill in the mass with random numbers
    for(int i=0; i < n; i ++){
        mass[i] = a + (int)(Math.random()*b);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        System.out.print(mass[i] + " ");
    }

    int maxInx = findMax(minData, mass);

    for(int i = minData.length; i < mass.length; i++){
        if(mass[i] <= mass[minData[maxInx]]){
            minData[maxInx] = i;
            maxInx = findMax(minData, mass);
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    for(int i : minData)
    System.out.print(i + " ");

}
public static int findMax(int[] minData, int[] mass){
    int res = 0;
    int max = mass[minData[0]];
    if (max < mass[minData[1]]){
        max = mass[minData[1]];
        res = 1;
    }
    if (max < mass[minData[2]]){
        max = mass[minData[2]];
        res = 2;
    }
    return res;
}
}
```

Но я еще пробовал переводить массив в строку и сортировать массив, ну и потом методом indexOf искать индексы элементов, но почему-то метод indexOf всегда выдает -1, почему так?

```
public class sort_mass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;

    int[] mass = new int[n];

    int a = 0, b = 10;
    //fill in the mass with random numbers
    for(int i=0; i < n; i ++){
        mass[i] = a + (int)(Math.random()*b);
    }
    String str = Arrays.toString(mass);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        System.out.print(mass[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        if(mass[i] < mass[i+1]){
            int temp = mass[i];
            mass[i] = mass[i+1];
            mass[i+1] = temp;
            i = -1;
        }
    }
}
}
```